# Javascript/jQuery: How can I invoke an "onchange()" callback at page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net Core web form with many groups of input items that can be hidden or displayed, depending on values entered by the user and stored in the database.

This is the callback that "shows" or "hides" submenus whenever a user changes the value in the dropdown menu, it works fine:

```
$('#DW_Answers_Q430').change(function (e) {
    let a = $('#DW_Answers_Q430').val();
    if (a == "None")
      $('#DW_Q430_grp').css('display','none');
    else $('#DW_Q430_grp').css('display','block');
});
```

Q: How can I invoke this callback when then "Edit" menu loads, to ensure the submenus are displayed or hidden correctly, depending on the value loaded from the database?

This is what I've tried:

**Edit.cshtml:**

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            ...
            dw_refresh();
            ...
        };
    </script>
}
```

**site.js:**

```
function dw_refresh() {
    console.log('dw_refresh()...');   // <-- dw_refresh() gets invoked
    ...
    var a = $('#D_Answers_Q430').val();
    $('#DW_Answers_Q430').val(a).change();  // <-- But the callback never gets invoked
    ...
```

Q: How can I invoke my callback, to ensure the submenus are displayed correctly when the "Edit" pages first loads?

---

**SOLUTION:**

1. Get rid of dw_refresh()
2. Substitute `bind('load change')`:

   ```
   $('#DWare_Answers_Q430').bind('load change', function () { 
      let a = $('#DW_Answers_Q430').val();
      console.log('DW_Answers_Q430, val:', a);
      if (a == "None")
         $('#DW_Q430_grp').css('display','none');
      else $('#DW_Q430_grp').css('display','block');
   });
   ```

Comment: Hi, You can try with ```$on('load','change' , function() {});```

Comment: @Himanshu Saxena - thank you.  "$on(...)" gives a syntax error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $on is not defined`.  But you pointed me in the right direction!  I wasn't aware that jQuery allowed *multiple* events.  My working solution is posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
$('#DW_Answers_Q430').val(a).change();
```

`.change()` is an event listener **setter** that should have a handler function passed in.

To trigger the `change` event, what you need is:

```
$('#DW_Answers_Q430').val(a).trigger("change");
```

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Thank you, but that whole "$('#DW_Answers_Q430').val(a).change();" stuff was a Wrong Turn.  All I wanted to do was invoke the callback so it would show/hide the submenus, based on the value loaded with the "Edit" page.  ACTUAL SOLUTION: `$('#DW_Answers_Q430').trigger('change');`